# Can't run web application, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError?

Tags: java, html, web-applications, java-8

I'm writing a Java web application, but whenever I try to access my model class the program crashes and the following error appears:

> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error allocating a servle instance
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class servicios.ServletControl
> has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than
> those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.7.0_79

After verifying, both the web app and the java project, they are running on JDK 8.0. and Java is correctly installed

> bove@Bove-PC:~$ java -version
>
> java version "1.8.0_45" Java(TM) SE
> Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
> Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

[image] Can someone help me identify the reason of this error?

Comment: Do you have Java 7 installed as well? Uninstall it. Or find what thing is still referring to it.

Comment: I uninstalled JDK 7 and reinstalled netbeans, that solved the problem. Thank You!